# The State Parameter in the Google OAuth 2 Process in Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-api-java-client

Please I need a quick help on how to add the "state" parameter to a authorization request to the Google OAuth 2 service using the Java Client Library. According to the docs, the OAuth provider is said to roundtrip this parameter to keep an application state through the authorzation process. My app needs this to determine which user is doing what.
I've searched online and I've come across  a lot of junks. Please help me out, I'm running out of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At some time (depending on your implementation) you have an instance of `AuthorizationRequestUrl`. Call its [`setState(String state)`](http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.10.1-beta/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/AuthorizationRequestUrl.html#setState%28java.lang.String%29) method to set the `state` parameter.

Comment: I never used that class. I'm using GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl. After calling its build() method to get the actual URL, I had to manually append "&state="+stateData to it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong. I of course meant an instance of `AuthorizationRequestUrl`, which has a `setState()` method. `GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl` is [deprecated](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.7.0-beta/index.html?com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/draft10/GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl.html) since version 1.7.0 of the library, which is quite old. As you never specified the version you are using, my answer was always based on the newest version.

Comment: I'm scared of the deprecation too. But the examples I say pointed me to that. I learnt the recent implementations now use Credentials. Unfortunately I can't refactor my code now as I'm really behind schedule. I'll do that in some other iterations. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using the class `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl`, set the `clientID`, `redirectURL` and `scope`. Then call the `build()` method to build the request string then append `&state=stateData` to the string (where `stateData` is the data you want to roundtrip).

Hope this helps other people.